# SwiftUI, indexing the result of ViewBuilder

Tags: tuples, swiftui, builder

I am trying to implement a custom view with similar functionality to `TabView`. I am initialising the displayed tabs using a `ViewBuilder`. However, this means that when I pass multiple views into the initialiser, the content is a `TupleView`. How do I display only one of the contained views at a time?

```
struct TabbedView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    @State var selected:Int = 0
    var content:Content

    var body: some View {
        content
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content:() -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabbedView {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, maybe it is not very SwiftUIyish, but it works ;)

```
struct TabbedView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    @State var selected:Int = 0
    var content:[Content]

    var body: some View {
        content[selected]
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content:() -> [Content]) {
        self.content = content()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabbedView { [
            Text("A"),
            Text("B")
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I might have to resort to this, it must be possible to do it in the same way as TabView does though, also, I think this would mean that all the elements of  content would have to be the same type, though I could get around this by using AnyView

Comment: Hi Ben, not necessarily "it has to be" because maybe Apple uses internally some private functions we do not have... ;)